# Unbale to start tomcat 6 after RAM + JVM upgradation

Tags: tomcat6, startup

I have upgraded Windows XP - PC RAM from 1GB to 3GB. Since JVM had some problem Eclipse Helios, I had to reinstall it and I did clean installation.

I have installed jdk7( jdk-7-ea-bin-b88-windows-i586-08_apr_2010.exe ). 
Now my tomcat( Apache Tomcat Version 6.0.16 ) doesn't start.
Log says

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 
javax/management/MalformedObjectNameException : 
Unsupported major.minor version 51.3
```

So I installed latest version of Tomcat i.e. Tomcat-6.0.29. Log says

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: 
Incompatible magic value 1853108037 in class file javax/management/MXBean
```

Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah it looks like Tomcat isn't compatible with JDK7 [This](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=tomcat+jdk7) to me says there are bugs